# Why io_submit(..., nr, ...) might submit less requests than nr?

Tags: linux, solid-state-drive, aio

I'm using `io_submit(..., nr, ...)` with nr up to 128 but I usually get fewer requests submitted.

According to the manual [IO_SUBMIT(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/io_submit.2.html), this is legit but I wonder: why? Also, is there a way to know which request was submitted right away - without checking `io_getevents()`?

From the manual:

> On success, io_submit() returns the number of iocbs submitted (**which
>     may be less than nr, or 0 if nr is zero**).  For the failure return,
>     see NOTES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible reason you're getting fewer results submitted is that you've reached a limit of 128 requests outstanding.  Maybe you called `io_submit` with 128, and then  call it again before all 128 requests have completed?  See the `nr_requests` entry in sysfs for your device for the limit on the number of requests its willing to handle:

```
# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/nr_requests
128
```

It's up to your code to track how many requests are outstanding and to avoid trying to call `io_submit` with a number of requests that'd push it over this limit.

Now, that might not be why your call is submitting fewer requests than you asked.  If you look at [the kernel source, in `fs/aio.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/aio.c), you can see all the failure conditions in `__io_submit_one` that could trigger a short response.  There could be argument problems with one of the requests, or maybe it can't allocate slab memory for the `kiocb`, etc.  But most likely, it's `aio_get_req` that's failing due to that `nr_requests` queue depth limit.

If you look at the `SYSCALL_DEFINE3(io_submit...` in that same file, you can see it's straightforward to figure out which requests weren't submitted.  It's simply the position in the array you handed to `io_submit`.  For example, if `io_submit` returns `5`, then you know that the requests that you submitted in array indices 0-4 have been submitted.  Anything between 5 and `nr - 1` has not been submitted.

Comment: Thank you sir!

In my case I was submitting 128 requests but only one was submitted and no error value was returned. Anyway, the pointers you provided me are all I need to delve deeper into the matter.

Regarding how to understand which requests aren't submitted, I think that's a missing piece of information that should be in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason to cause `1` returned by `io_submit` with param `nr` > `1` is that param `iocbpp` is not an array of `iocb` pointer. A mistake I made is passing the address of the `iocb` array:

```
struct iocb* io_request = (struct iocb *)(malloc((sizeof(struct iocb)) * len));
//... io_prep_pwrite stuff
ret = io_submit(ctx, len, &req.io_request); // return 1
```

If I passing +1 address will get EFAULT(bad address):

```
struct iocb* io_request = (struct iocb *)(malloc((sizeof(struct iocb)) * len));
//... io_prep_pwrite stuff
ret = io_submit(ctx, len, (&req.io_request)+1); // return -14
```

To fix:

```
struct iocb* request[len];
struct iocb* io_request = (struct iocb *)(malloc((sizeof(struct iocb)) * len));
//... io_prep_pwrite stuff
for (int i = 0; i < len_; i++) {
    request[i] = &(io_request[i]);
}
ret = io_submit(ctx, len, request); // return len
```

Thanks to Mike. As Mike mentioned, argument problems with one of the requests will cause a short response, but no error value is return by `io_submit` to debug with. We can pass `iocbpp` at return position, to get the error value, `iocbpp + 5` in his example, `iocbpp + 1` in my example.